# why the upper part of recyclerview item is erased?

Tags: android, xml

the upper part of recyclerview item is erased in some phones and is normal in other phones as the images below.

the first image is normal which from samsung phone (android 12 )

the second image has the problem which from huawi phone (android 8)

[image]
[image]

this is the code

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="5dp">


    <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
        android:id="@+id/itemImage"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:riv_oval="true"

        />

    <View
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:id="@+id/viewSupporter2"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/itemImage"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/itemImage"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/itemImage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/itemImage"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/diseasename"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:text="disease name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/black"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/viewSupporter2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/itemImage"
         />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/diseasenickname"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:text= "disease nickname"
        android:textColor="@color/teal_700"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/viewSupporter2"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/itemImage"
        tools:ignore="NotSibling" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing a basic mistake of having your cards at fixed height of `70dp`. Change them to be `wrap_content` and tweak margins/paddings of your layout instead to achieve the size you need.

While it looks ok on device you designed it for you can see it cannot fit `TextView`s on the other one so they ends up being clipped (on top). Actually you can even break it on your Samsung if you go into device settings and increase font size.

You have to let your card view "grow" in those cases so unrestraining height it is the way to go. Although you might consider adding maxlines to your textviews so they don't get too out of hand with maximum font size.

Comment: thanks for reply,
i changed it  to wrap content but the problem  is still

Comment: @mahmoudelmahgoub I think right now your card will just get whatever size to fit your image view since it's the only element that's constrained to `parent`. You'll need to change your constraints so you have a vertical chain with your text views.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is your second device is set to a larger system font size than the first one. The `dp` system is designed so that things look consistent on different devices, and you can see that the `ImageView` takes up pretty much the same amount of space on both - the space around it is the same, the layout *looks* the same.

But you have to account for the user changing their overall text size, which is what's happening on your second image. See how the text is just *bigger*? Not just in your list items - the **diseases** text is taller than the hamburger icon on this one, the tab headers are much closer together because the words are wider...

You have three options in this case

- use `dp` instead of `sp` for the text sizes (so they're consistent and don't scale to the user's preference)
- make sure your fixed layout has enough space for those larger text sizes
- make sure it can expand as necessary to fit them

---

The first option is ok *sometimes*, when you have text that's already large enough for everyone, and you want to maintain some kind of visual consistency (like a fixed design where things are a certain size etc). **Don't do this as a way to get around the limitations of having to provide accessible content, that scales so the user can read it.**

---

The flexible layout approach is what [Pawel's suggesting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73423335/13598222) - basically design your layout so it can grow if necessary. You can use the `minWidth` and `minHeight` layout attributes for this (and `layout_constraintHeight_min` in `ConstraintLayout`) to design how you *want* it to look, but use things like `wrap_content` and constraints to allow it to grow *beyond that* if necessary. That way you get it looking how you like, but if the user needs bigger text, it compromises.

And don't worry if you don't like how it looks with large text - that's not important! What's important is that the user can read it, and everything's visible and accessible. Nothing cut off, nothing overlapping anything, everything clickable etc. The user is the one making the compromise between style and practicality, and they probably don't have a choice, so just making it usable in that situation is the main thing.

---

The middle option is the fixed layout that has enough space for the larger text settings. This is actually what's recommended in the Material Design spec - I can't link directly to the *Two line* version, but [go here](https://material.io/components/lists#specs) and scroll down - there are some similar to what you're doing:

[image: Material Design specs for some two-line list item layouts]

Those measurements are all in *dp* - notice that the top line's position is defined by where its **baseline** is, the line the text "rests" on, relative to the top of the layout. You can do that with:

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
app:firstBaselineToTopHeight="32dp"
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

And then the text *below* has its baseline relative to the bottom of the *first*

```
app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/firstTextView"
app:layout_marginBaseline="20dp"
```

or you could constrain it to the top of the layout like the first one, with a value of *32 + 20dp*.

Notice that this design leaves space for the text to grow vertically (up from the baseline, which is in a fixed position). If you use the [Material Design type scale](https://material.io/design/typography/the-type-system.html#type-scale) (which is a bunch of standard text styles and font sizes with names like *Subtitle* and *Body1*) then those list item specs should have enough room to hold the text even at the larger font settings. Both lines in that image can pretty much double in height and still fit

The nice thing about these specs is someone's done the work coming up with a design for you! And they're working with fixed sizes, so you get a nice consistent look to your lists